# Why is background not being applied to UITableView on iPad?

Tags: ios, background-color, uitableview

On an iPad View, I added a UITableView object, set its Style to Grouped, and the Background is set to Clear Color. Running the app on the simulator, I can see that the Background that I chose was not applied. (The background is still the default grayish color). I applied other colors but same thing happens. Even on the xib file, I can't see that the background color changes. Why is the background color not taking effect on my UITableView object? I'm currently using Xcode 4.3. Is this a bug on this version?

Note: This is working on iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `backgroundView` instead of the `backgroundColor` on the table view, like this:

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
>     self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = ...;
> }
> ```